# Replacing multiplication of matrix elements by application of these elements as functions

Tags: functions, matrix, operators

I want to realize the following idea in Mathematica.

I've got a matrix

```
{{a,b},{c,d}}
```

which is multiplied to a vector `{h,k}` leading to

```
{{a h + b k}, {c h + d k}}.
```

Imagine now that `a` is an operator and I want to apply it to `h`, instead of multiplying. 
Primitive substitution `{a h -> a@h}` helps, but it is not quite a good approach while it's not working in more sophisticated cases.

Thank you!

**EDIT1:**
The problem is solved partially, all comments are very useful. But still I am a little bit stacked, so I'm posting the update trying to explain my exact problem.

The problem is following. I want to construct the matrix

```
{{a[x], b},{c, d}}
```

where `a[x]` is an operator (function) and `b,c` and `d` are arbitrary expressions (which are symbolic in general). After applying the operation

```
{{a[x], b},{c, d}}.{{h}, {k}}
```

I want to obtain

```
{{a[h] + b k}, {c h + d k}}
```

I want this operation to work not only for numbers and functions as it was proposed in answers below but with arbitrary symbolic expressions. I mean I want Mathematica to understand that if `x` and `p` are not functions but just variables, then `x*p` means multiplication, otherwise it means `x[p]`.

Moreover I want this operation to work in more general cases, e.g.

```
{{a[x], b},{c, d}}.M.Transpose[{{a[x], b},{c, d}}],
```

where `M` is an arbitrary matrix.

I would be very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Have you seen `Inner`, the generalization of `Dot`?

Comment: For your last example, what is the expected output? Does the `a[x]` in `Transpose[{{a[x], b},{c, d}}]` act to the left on `M` (in which case an order of operations needs to be specified), or does it act to the *right*, leaving the expression as a function?

Comment: One of the ways to accomplish this is to replace the non-functions with pure functions that are products, e.g. replace `b` with `b*# &` and leave `a` as `a`, and use the `Inner` answer below, but see my last comment: we need an answer to this before giving a complete answer.

Comment: @march Concerning your question: I want this matrix to act to the left on `M`

Comment: Which means that `a` acts (as a function) to the left on the matrix elements of `M`? So then this operation is not associative, which means you need to choose: does the left matrix act on `M` first or does the right matrix act on `M` first?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter which does it first. I mean that acting by `a[ ]` to some expression `x` leads to `a[x]` (from both sides) and acting repeatedly leads to `a[a[x]]`. Acting of `a[x]` to other variable `c` which is not function leads to `c*a[x]`

Simple example

     `{{a, b},{c, d}} . {{x, 0},{0, y}}.{{a, c}, {b, d}} = {{a^2 x + b^2 y, a c x + b d y}, {a c x + b d y, c^2 x + d^2 y}}`

I want to replace here `a^2 x` by `a[a[x]]` and `a c x` by `c*a[x]`

Comment: Sorry, I want to replace `a^2` by `a[a[x]]` in `[[1,1]]` element, `a c x` by `c*a[x]` in `[[1,2]]` element and `a c x` by `a[c x]` in `[[2,1]]` element

Comment: You say to replace `a c x` by `c*a[x]` in `[[1,2]]` and `a c x` by `a[c x]` in `[[2, 1]]`. That is *exactly* what I mean by non-associative. I think this means that you have to do these calculations left to right. Let me see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picking up on Marius tip on Inner in the comments:

```
Inner[Apply[#1, {#2}] &, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {h, k}]
```

And @ciao offered a better version in comments:

```
Inner[#1[#2] &, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {h, k}]
```

Comment: Or just `Inner[#1[#2] &, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {h, k}]`...

Comment: Yes, thank you. But it works only if all the elements of the matrix are functions. And what about the case if only 'a' is a function?
@ciao

Comment: @NikitaVostrosablin `Inner[Function[{a, b}, 
  If[NumericQ[a], a*b, a[b]]], {{Sin, 2}, {3, d}}, {h, k}]`

Comment: @ciao Thank you! It works :)

Comment: @ciao @VitalyKaurov  Btw how can I do the same using symbols? I've tried 

`SetAttributes[{b, c, d, h, k}, NumericFunction]` 

and then

 `Inner[Function[{a, b}, If[Attributes[a] === {NumericFunction}, a*b, a[b]]], {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {h, k}]`

 It works but not in more sophisticated case if I want to multiply again the result by `Transpose[ {{a, b}, {c, d}}]`  for example

Comment: @Nikita, maybe you should consider posting what your *actual* problem is; I suspect there might be a better way to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If all the elements in the matrix are functions, you can also use

```
Block[{Times = (# @ #2 &)}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}.{h, k}]
```

> {a[h] + b[k], c[h] + d[k]}

Comment: Of course, the latter only works if `a` sorts before `h`, `b` sorts before `k`, etc.

Comment: @march, right -- and that is quite an if. I guess i should delete that part.