# Defining a matrix with elements acting as operators

Tags: functions, matrix, operators

This question is directly related with [my previous one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114728/replacing-multiplication-of-matrix-elements-by-application-of-these-elements-as).

I'll try to be more specific here. I have a matrix

```
{{a[x],b},{c,d}},
```

where `a[x]` is a function of its argument `x` and `b,c,d` are some arbitrary expressions. I want this matrix to act in the following way

```
{{a[x], b},{c, d}}.{{h}, {k}} = {{a[h] + b k}, {c h + d k}}.
```

It means that if a[x] is multiplied on some expression (multiplied from the left), it ***acts*** on it instead of just being multiplied. Expressions are multiplied in ordinary way.

One way to accomplish this is apllying

```
Inner[#1[#2] &, {{a, b*# &}, {c*# &, d*# &}}, {h, k}].
```

Now let us consider more sophisticated situation. I want this matrix to be able to act from the ***right*** as well. I mean I want to implement following operation

```
{{a[x], b},{c, d}}.M.Transpose[{{a[x], b},{c, d}}],
```

where `M` is arbitrary *2x2* matrix, e.g. `M = {{x, 0},{0, y}}`.

In the case of simple inner product this operation leads to

```
{{a, b},{c, d}} . {{x, 0},{0, y}}.{{a, c}, {b, d}} = {{a^2 x + b^2 y, a c x + b d y}, {a c x + b d y, c^2 x + d^2 y}}
```

And I want this operation to give me the same matrix with replacing:  `a^2`by `a[a[x]]` in `[[1,1]]` element, `a c x` by `c*a[x]` in `[[1,2]]` element and `a c x` by `a[c x]` in `[[2,1]]` element.

I would be very grateful for any ideas.

Comment: If `h` and `k` are elements of a *finite set* then you can write everything as matrices because `a[x]` is then discrete, too. Then one could use `KroneckerProduct` to construct the required larger matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be done with a custom function for the first argument of `Inner` that treats `a` differently (it's just a more convenient form of expressing your original idea). For example, consider this:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a, x_] := a[x]
f[x_, a] := a[x]
f[x_, y_] := x y
```

Now for your first example:

```
Inner[f, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {h, k}]
(* {b k + a[h], c h + d k} *)
```

For the second example, note that `Dot[a, b]` is just `Inner[Times, a, b]`. So we can simply rephrase the first expression in terms of `Inner` and use our custom function `f`.

```
ClearAll@dot
dot[lists__List] := Fold[Inner[f, #, #2] &, First@{lists}, Rest@{lists}]

dot[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{x, 0}, {0, y}}, {{a, c}, {b, d}}]
(* {{b (b y + a[0]) + a[a[x]], d (b y + a[0]) + c a[x]}, 
    {b d y + a[c x],c^2 x + d^2 y}} *)
```

Comment: I would have been tempted to use `NonCommutativeMultiply[]` with `Inner[]` and then use replacement rules at the end, but this is more stylish. :)

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for